# How to unwrap the html contents from `content` element

Tags: angular5

I am getting the `html` from backend including html tags. the problem is, when i use the

```
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Main title</h1>
  <content [innerHTML]="title"></content>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Main title</h1>
  <div[innerHTML]="title"></div>
</div>
```

Both way, my css not works:

```
.parent > h2{
  color:green;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

How to prevent `content` nor `div` additional elements from template?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qewhna)

Answer (score 0):

You could modify your css to this.

```
.parent > * > h2 {
  color: green;
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
```

Hope this helps.